# Использование переменных в базовом классе, объявленных  в классе наследнике

Tags: классы, c++

Есть два класса, один - родитель, другой - наследник.

```
**Base.h**
class Derived;//предв. объявление
сlass Base
{
    public:  void pic();
}

**Derived.h**
#include"Base.h"
сlass Derived:public Base
{
   public: static const char* str_to_bckgrnd;  
}
const char* Derived::str_to_bckgrnd="Images/environment/background/lev_1/33.png";

**Base_func_implementation.h**
#include"Base.h"
void  Base::pic()
{
     i_a=ImageAdd(str_to_bckgrnd);
}
```

я хочу в базовом классе использовать переменную-строку,которую объявляю в наследнике. думал сделать в файле с базовым классе предварительное объявление класса наследника, не помогло.

вот такие ошибки

```
IntelliSense: identifier "str_to_bckgrnd" is undefined

'str_to_bckgrnd' : undeclared identifier
```

Как можно считать переменную с класса наследника? если конечно это можно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто объявите в базовом классе виртуальный метод, который возвращает нужную вам информацию и реализуйте его в наследнике.

```
**Base.h**
сlass Base
{
    public:  void pic();
    protected: const char* get_something() = 0;
}

**Derived.h**
#include"Base.h"
сlass Derived:public Base
{
   public: static const char* str_to_bckgrnd; 
   private: const char* get_something() { return str_to_bckgrnd; }
}
const char* Derived::str_to_bckgrnd="Images/environment/background/lev_1/33.png";

**Base_func_implementation.h**
#include"Base.h"
void  Base::pic()
{
     i_a=ImageAdd(get_something());
}
```

Comment: О, вы меня опередили.

Comment: спасибо) а для чего функцию  get_something() в базовом классе объявлять protected, а в наследуемом писать как private?

Comment: @Dexter384, читайте в книжке про спецификаторы доступа, можно сделать и по-другому, зависит от того, что вы хотите добиться. Для вашего примера достаточно таких спецификаторов. Ну и "Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом)".

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, не знаю... такое извращение пойдет? :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class parent{
    public:
    char *suda;

}A;
class derived : public parent{
    public:
    char stroka;
    void iderived(){
        stroka='X';
        A.suda=&stroka;
        cout<<*A.suda<<endl;
    }

}D;

void main()
{
    D.iderived();
    char a=*A.suda;
    printf("%c \n",a);
}
```